# Python // create XML File

Tags: python, xml

I'm struggling with printing out an `xml-file`.

What I wanna do is to iterate through my list of test numbers until the list is empty.

But I'm not getting to the point, where it even prints out anything, since I get a syntax error for the print command `(***-Line)`.

I would be fine with getting it printed out to the console, but right now I'm stuck with the syntax error.

Any ideas on how to fix that syntax error?

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder


E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
ITEM = E.item
attributeValue = E.attributeValue
part = E.part
a = 300 #Testwert

l = [10,20,30,44,76876,9009809] #Personennummern
i = 0 #Indexwert


while len(l) > 0:
    Document = ITEM(
                 attributeValue(str("2019-12-03"), id="1026"),
                 attributeValue(str("2019-12-03"), id="1028"),
                 attributeValue(str("FATCA Schriftverkehr"), id="1023"),
                 attributeValue(str(l[i]), id="1022"),
                 attributeValue(str("FATCA"), id="1031"),
                 attributeValue(str(a), id = "1025", url="Test-URL", contenttype = "application/pdf/"),
                 part(str(a), type="base"),
                 type="1007"
            ) 
    ***print lxml.etree.tostring(Document, pretty_print=True)
    del l[i]
```

Comment: Can you share the complete syntax error text you received to aid in debugging?

Comment: `"..."` already create a value of type `str`; there's no need to pass it to `str` again.

Comment: There's also no reason to destructively consume the value of `l`: `for val in l: ...`, with `val` used in place of `l[i]`. The `del l[i]` can be dropped entirely.

Comment: And on that note, you aren't incrementing `i`.

Comment: And, there is no syntax error in the code you posted (after removing the `***`, anyway), *if* you are using Python 2. If you are using Python 3, `print` is a *function*, not a statement. `print(lxml.etree.tostring(Document, pretty_print=True))`

Comment: Adding brackets to the print function helped me to get rid of the syntax error. I thought i tried that before, but somehow i messed that up. Cheers for the help

Comment: Yep i worked with some old code fragments. Gonna read about how to write it in Python 3 and rework it. Thanks for the hint